# how to remove only charactres in a given string in java?

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to remove only `[A-z|a-z]` like this:

```
String input ="A021001208A 711100609C 01111";
String clean = input.replaceAll("\\D+^\\s+",""); 
System.out.println(clean.toString());
```

but the above code also removes the spaces; I don't want to remove space.

The expected output is:

```
021001208 711100609 01111
```

Please help me to formate the reg-ex to remove only characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than use a positive character class, use a negated one. The regex you want is:

```
[^\d\s]
```

Which means "any character other than a digit or a whitespace".
When coded as java, it looks like:

```
String clean = input.replaceAll("[^\\d\\s]","");
```

Comment: its removing the space between string, i want to keep the space and it should remove only A-Z or a-z

Comment: @jcrshankar Better show us your actual code, actual text, and output you got in your question, because neither this nor the regex in my answer will remove spaces.

Comment: @RohitJain they could be tabs not spaces, in which case `\s` instead - see edited answer (which will still work if the chars are spaces)

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `[a-zA-Z]` then:

```
String clean = input.replaceAll("(?i)[A-Z]+","");
```

`(?i)` is ignore case embedded flag expression.

Comment: its removing the space between string, i want to keep the sapce and it should remove only A-Z or a-z

Comment: I don't believe it is removing the space. Are you sure you tested it correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will replace all occurence of alphabet from the given string.

```
String clean = input.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
```

Comment: input.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]", "");  this is fine to remove the characters.. any reg-ex pattern for the same.

Comment: @jcrshankar Above is also regex. Seems you are searching for some complex answer...yes??

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `[a-zA-Z]` regular expression. So your `.replaceAll()` method will look like as below :

```
 String clean = input.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]","");
```

Comment: ya this will give my output, any regex pattern for the same.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]` is regex pattern only. And FYI, if it works, then `[a-zA-Z]+` will work too.